# Why this small bit of code takes 11 seconds to execute these few database calls?

Tags: mysql, go

I have this bit of code:

```
package tradebot

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/Philipp15b/go-steam/tradeoffer"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func AcceptTrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    var tradeId tradeoffer.TradeOfferId
    var sTradeId string
    if _, has := vars["TradeId"]; has {
        var err error
        sTradeId = vars["TradeId"]
        id, err := strconv.ParseUint(vars["TradeId"], 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "Error accepting trade offer", 500)
        }
        tradeId = tradeoffer.TradeOfferId(id)
    }

    err := Trader.Accept(tradeId)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        http.Error(w, "Failed to accept trade try again after", 500)
    }
    rows, err := Db.Query("SELECT DepositedBy, Price FROM skinbank WHERE tradeofferid=? AND accepted=?", sTradeId, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Your trade offer was accepted but there was an error on our side. Please open a ticket with the trade ID: "+sTradeId+" so we can address this issue. Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience", 500)
    }
    foundRows := false
    for rows.Next() {
        foundRows = true
        var price float64
        var depositedby string
        err = rows.Scan(&depositedby, &price)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, "Your trade offer was accepted but there was an error on our side. Please open a ticket with the trade ID: "+sTradeId+" so we can address this issue. Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience", 500)
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, "Your trade offer was accepted but there was an error on our side. Please open a ticket with the trade ID: "+sTradeId+" so we can address this issue. Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience", 500)
        }
        log.Println(depositedby, price)
        _, err := Db.Query("UPDATE accounts SET credits = credits + ? WHERE steamid=?", price, depositedby)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, "Your trade offer was accepted but there was an error on our side. Please open a ticket with the trade ID: "+sTradeId+" so we can address this issue. Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience", 500)
        }
    }

    _, err = Db.Query("UPDATE skinbank SET accepted=? WHERE tradeofferid=?", 1, sTradeId)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Your trade offer was accepted but there was an error on our side. Please open a ticket with the trade ID: "+sTradeId+" so we can address this issue. Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience", 500)
    }
    log.Println("Trade accepted: " + sTradeId)
    if foundRows {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/profile", 303)
    } else {
        http.Error(w, "No trade with that id, either doesn't exist or already accepted.", 500)
    }
}
```

It is mostly just a few MySQL calls to the database to update / get a bit of information, I was wondering if anybody can tell me what I have done inefficiently here that it's causing this to take 11 seconds to run (with about 6 items to loop in the `for rows.Next()` call.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch sorry the profiler?

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch no I'm not sure how to do that. I just have a middleware that tells me how long a response took in this case it was 11 seconds which is brutal.

Comment: Well, then learn to use the profiler. It might very much point you to the offending code. And if that is a MySQL query you will then have to do an `Explain` on that query to see if you've missed putting an index on a field.

Answer (score 2):

**Specimen A:**

```
rows, err := Db.Query("SELECT DepositedBy, Price FROM skinbank 
WHERE tradeofferid=? AND accepted=?", sTradeId, 0)
```

**Specimen B: (inside for loop)**

```
_, err := Db.Query("UPDATE accounts SET credits = credits + ? WHERE steamid=?", price, depositedby)
```

**Specimen C:**

```
_, err = Db.Query("UPDATE skinbank SET accepted=? WHERE tradeofferid=?", 1, sTradeId)
```

Put profiling timing statement around these. If you don't know how, ask. Show the table schemas if you need more help by issuing `show create table skinbank` and `show create table credits`. This will enable some clue on indexes. Tell us the rowcounts of the two tables.

If you have a ton of rows, it is possible without proper indexes that you are performing tablescans, not fast lookups, to get to the rows in the update where clause. Heck, in the select too. Right now you don't know the timings.

At the very least, have indexes on

```
skinbank(tradeofferid,accepted) -- a composite index, useful for Specimen A
credits(steamid) -- useful for Specimen B
```

As for specimen C, it should pick up the left-most of the composite index just suggested. So a separate index on just skinbank(tradeofferid) is overkill if you are going the composite route.

Comment: "Put profiling timing statement" is this how you do profiling in Go? Such a  Hipster language!

Comment: time.Now(), but I would save profiling to the db rather than stream it out. Have a little record of things

Comment: Using `time.Since(start)` can be useful for very small localized things where you just want something very quick and dirty. For *anything* else use the [Go profiling tools](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/pprof/), see [The Go Blog: Profiling Go Programs](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs). (Note, if you already serve HTTP with your Go code you can just [`import _ "net/http/pprof"`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) to get your HTTP server to serve out profiling information).

Comment: the OP could have given me the profiling info, and the table structures with indexes, and rowcounts, in 5 minutes. I guess he figured it out